# Feature selection of Gabor filter

Tags: filters, data-analysis, image-processing

I am working with Gabor filter with level set method [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.3145). As you known, gabor filter gave many filter output. Some of them is not necessary. Could you suggest to me some method that can choose best filter ouput that satisfy maximum the difference between object (zebra) and background that are separated by a contour (white circle)as figure. Thank you. Now, I am working in image segmentation, hence, these best filter outputs will give more accuracy

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should try to use a template matching method.
Your eyes see a star, but it doesn't really exist as it has the same colour as the background. it's just your brain trying to complete a shape.

As the knowledge of the star shape comes from you and not from the image itself, look for methods using this kind of prior.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Template matching is good method but it needs training data. In my situation, I don't want to use training data. Do you know other option?

Comment: Is your background known ? In this special example it consists in horizontal stripes which can be ignored. In this special case, you can try filters that are reacting to edges which are not horizontal.
I'm not sure if it can help, try to step back from your problem. Then, write "what I look for", "in which context", "why is it different from the rest of the pictures". I really think this could help

Comment: I updated my question. It will replace previous image by zebra image to make more clearly. I am looking for a method that can remove filter outputs in gabor filter. Let see the my reference to see more detail